# is it possible to add separate frontend like react for existing flask python project

Tags: reactjs, flask, frontend, backend

Joined in an existing project with flask python, it is a combined backend with template to show html on front end, is there a way I add a separate from end framework like react for new features? like the existing ones are kept untouched, just add new features with react in front end?
or have to implement new features in the flask?

basically the concern is with flask python, websites not that modern. I know we can also use bootstrap or semantic UI,but not sure. quite new in react. for the flask, get to know from last week...any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is there a way? Yes. These questions are too broad and there are resources online that already explain how to do this. Whether or not you have to add new features to the flask back end depends on what features already exist.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to convert the existing flask app to a [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) the classic way that flask uses is that the server returns a template (HTML page) using information in the DB. Another way is instead of returning a template, the server should returns [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data that the client (React, VueJS, Angular, Android, IOS...) can get it (with tools like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)...) and display it to the user.

[Flask-RESTful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is an extension for Flask that adds support for quickly building REST APIs.

Comment: I know how to axios with backend in react. now the flask using template to return the HTML page, converting the whole web is painful and time consuming...

Comment: You can upload react using CDN but that's not the best solution.